# PHP 7.1 iconv() converts currency symbols into LB and EUR

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre, php-7.1

I just updated my vagrant box from PHP 7.0 to PHP 7.1, and now some weird things happen with regex:

```
$filename = 'hello£€';
$filename = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $filename);
$filename = preg_replace('![^\-\.\pL\pN\s]+!u', '', $filename);
echo $filename;
```

In PHP 7.1 I get `helloGBPEUR`!

It seems currency symbols are being converted to abbreviations:
e.g. `£` to `GBP` and `€` to `EUR`

My expected output is `hello`, to match how the software worked in PHP 7.0.

Comment: [Output is consistent between 7.0 and 7.1](https://3v4l.org/EijrT)

Comment: Are you doing an `iconv()` anywhere in your code? Or are these html entities rather than simple characters?

Comment: It's a test, so they are simply text strings. I'm looking at the configuration...

Comment: Works for me as expected.

Comment: Are you trying exactly what you're saying here or are you trying to simplify the code (and in the process removing the part that's actually broken?)

Comment: Yes, I have a `iconv()` call, I added it to the main post.

Comment: If you append the string //TRANSLIT to out_charset transliteration is activated. This means that when a character can't be represented in the target charset, it can be approximated through one or several similarly looking characters. [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading the documentation. Still I do not understand why it has a different behaviour on my box with tw different PHP version. I have to dig in the php.ini configuration. Thanks for you help guys.

Comment: Most likely the difference is not the PHP version per se, but the version of `iconv` each is using. Check your `phpinfo()` output.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's `iconv()` depends on the operating system's iconv() implementation. There may have been a bug in PHP 7.0 that prevented your request for ASCII//TRANSLIT to work as designed.

For operating system `iconv()` calls, the default is to convert the [Euro € symbol to EUR](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libiconv/libiconv-4/libiconv/lib/translit.def.auto.html).

Without the TRANSLIT, you will error out trying to convert the characters not present in ASCII:

> PHP Notice:  iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string

Flipping the operations can get you working as you intended:

```
% cat translit.php
<?php
$filename = 'hello£€';
$filename = preg_replace('![^\-\.\pL\pN\s]+!u', '', $filename);
$filename = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $filename);
echo $filename . "\n";
% php translit.php
hello
```

This works because your preg match looking for Unicode letter and numbers succeeds. Then you pass it to convert any remaining characters to ASCII.